# mapreduce parameters in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I wanted to know if mapreduce.* parameters are applicable in Spark.

As far as I know in Spark there is no buffer for the map output and for the reduce task the whole process is also different. Parameters like *mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb ,mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent or mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent* control these kind of buffers. 
I'm working in optimising parameters for spark tasks/jobs running in a hadoop/yarn cluster.

It is safe to say that these mapreduce parameters don't matter and that I should only care about spark.* parameters since the map, shuffle and reduce parts are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe because Spark doesn't use MapReduce as processing engine, but it interacts directly with YARN to submit operations. Thus, when you use Spark, there is no MapReduce job scheduled, but you have a Spark application and Spark jobs.

Comment: Just to confirm. Basically I should only tune spark.* and yarn.* parameters

Comment: Yes, for Spark application these are the relevant settings.